# How to configure service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a root service that has composition inside like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MapService {
   
  private rmap: RMap;

  init(props: Props) {
      this.rmap = new RMap(props);
  }

  getMapLayers() {
     return this.rmap.layers;
  }

}
```

Problem is that `new RMap();` has inside async functions. And when I use `getMapLayers()` from service it gives me error as `undefined`, because some functionality inside `new RMap()` are not ready. They are async.

How to solve this more properly?

As I mentioned above I get props from input:

```
@Input() props: Props;
constructor(private rMap: RMap) {
  this.rMap.init(this.props) {
 } 
}
```

But in anothe root service I get undefined on the line `this.rMap.interactiveMap.getSourceId();`:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SearchyService {
    constructor(private rMap: RMap) {
        this.drawResourceId = this.rMap.interactiveMap.getSourceId();
    } 
}
```

Because `RMap` has some async.

Comment: I could use APP_INITIALIZER in Angular, but it is not fit for me, because I want to pass props into `new RMap();` from component @Input() props. Because I use Angular Elements.

Comment: maybe the `SearchyService` get called before the `MapService`? Which functions are async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `async/await` for this, or the `promise.then` in order to wait for the function to be ready.

Something  like this:

```
async getMapLayers() {
    await this.map.getLayers()
}
```

And the place the you are calling the this function, will be like this:

```
async gettingLayers() {
  this.mapService.init();
  await this.mapService.getMapLayers()
}
```

You can read more about Promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: What is I call `this.mapService.getMapLayers()` in another component?  It is not in the same place

Comment: Also constructor of RMap() is not async, but some methods inside tis class are async. So I can not use `await new RMap();`

Comment: You can use the `getMapLayers()` anywhere after initializing the service, as the service is a singleton, you can init it one and then use the function anywhere you want after injecting the service. Regarding the second question, you can check the edited answer. The same idea with Async / Await.

Comment: I must pass parameters to `new RMap();` from Input component. It is required for initialization. So I can not initialize this in APP_INIT

Comment: it is ok. You will need the init once in the life of the app, then you can access the map from anywhere after that init

Comment: No, to initialize `new RMap(props)` I need to grap parameters from @Input() props: Props, how can I do this?

Comment: @Input() props: Props;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapService.init(this.props)
  }`

Comment: You can add more code and explanation in the question, so we can help more

Comment: Okay, I will post more details

Comment: I have posted some details